# How to define a HttpClientHandler for named HttpClient using HttpClientFactory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

Old code:

```
Client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials });

// set an default user agent string, some services does not allow emtpy user agents
if (!Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("User-Agent"))
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
```

Trying to implement the same using the new ASP.NET Core 2.1 HttpClientFactory:

```
services.AddHttpClient("Default", client =>
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(handler => new HttpClientHandler() { DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials });
```

Unfortunately, I get an HTTP 407 (Proxy Auth) error.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How does your question not have more up votes? There is almost nothing on google when you search this.

Answer (score 8):

It is usually advised to have a static class containing string constants for the names of the clients.

Something like:

```
public static class NamedHttpClients {
    public const string Default = "Default";
}
```

Then ensure that named client is configured correctly, which in your particular case would look like:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient(NamedHttpClients.Default, client => {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    })
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler() { 
        DefaultProxyCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials 
    });
```

From there you can get the client from an injected `IHttpClientFactory`

```
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.Default);
```

and used as intended.